# how to enable /static/css URL enable in django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-settings, django-1.3, django-static

When I use MEDIA_URL or STATIC_URL to point to /static/ currently set MEDIA_URL to /static/
 and using it in a path to CSS file like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}css/css.css" />
```

It points to `/static/css.css`, but trying `http://localhost/static/css.css` gives 404 error.

I have in settings:

```
.....
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = 'D:/programming/django_projects/ecomstore/'
.....
```

In urls.py I have point to static like this:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
     {'document_root':'D:/programming/django_projects/ecomstore/'}
```

So where problem is? Why it is showing 404, do I need to create some view for static files? Or is there some thing else wrong in my settings or urls.py ? Any response will be appreciated, as I am newbie in django.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to re-read the docs more closely: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Here's some things to note:

1. `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` are for user uploads (`FileField`s and `ImageField`s on your models). It should be its own folder; "media" is common.
2. `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` are for your static resources. It should also be its own folder; "static" is common.
3. Do *not* actually put anything in `STATIC_ROOT`. This directory is only for the output of the `collectstatic` management command in production.
4. Your static resources should go in your apps' "static" folder *or* a completely new and different directory (i.e. not `MEDIA_ROOT` or `STATIC_ROOT`). You then add the path to that directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`.
5. Don't add anything to urls.py. In development, Django will automatically serve anything in your apps "static" directories or any directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. In production, your webserver will be responsible for serving these files.